# What does אקים means?

Tags: words, vayechi, resurrection-of-the-dead, yirmiyahu--book-of

Does אקים means "I will resurrect" or "I will raise up"? Are these terms synonyms? Consider this:

> וְעָבְדוּ, אֵת יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵיהֶם, וְאֵת דָּוִד מַלְכָּם, אֲשֶׁר **אָקִים** לָהֶם.
>
> But they shall serve the LORD their God, and David their king, whom ***I
>   will raise up*** (or *I will resurrect*?) unto them.

My question is whether or not [Jeremiah 30:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1130.htm) (quoted above) is talking about the possibility of resurrection of David Hamelech to be the King Moshiach (as [Or HaChaim on Bereshis 49:11](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&perek=49&mefaresh=orah_haim) suggests):

> וי''א (סנהדרין צח:) דוד עצמו מלך המשיח דכתיב (יחזקאל ל''ז) ועבדי דוד
>   מלך עליהם

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I will establish

based on hebrew grammar from Jacob Wiengreen